# Project Reactor's Flux get failed item during handling error

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I need to handle `Flux` stream error and for that I need to know what exactly item is failed. Seems method `doOnError` should be appropriate for handling error, but with that I can only get exception and not a failed item. Is there any way to get both failed item and exception?

```
private void testFluxIterableFlow() {
    Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            .map(this::process)
            .doOnError(ex -> {
                ...
            })
            .doOnNext(processedValue -> ...)
            .subscribe();
}

private String process(Integer value) {
    if (value == 4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("error...");
    }
    return "processed " + value;
}
```

in this example, I need to receive failed item `4` and exception message in error handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a value causes an exception, you should treat the value as an exception cause.

It's up to you to decide whether it's worth adding a new exception type,

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WrongValueInStreamException extends RuntimeException {
    @Getter
    private final Object wrongValue;
}

public class StreamProcessor {
    public String process(Integer value) {
        if (value == 4) {
            throw new WrongValueInStreamException(4);
        }
        return "processed " + value;
    }
}
```

but it's a good practice as long as an exception conveys useful and related information:

```
.doOnError(WrongValueInStreamException.class::isInstance, e -> {
    final Object value = ((WrongValueInStreamException) e).getWrongValue();
    // use 'value'
})
```

Comment: thank you, it works, but as for me it's like a workaround.

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi I agree, but I couldn't find any API for this case

Answer (score 4):

A little late here but in case someone else needs it... Probably what you would want to do is instead use onErrorContinue. Note that this method will drop the error item from the flux and continue processing so be sure to keep that in mind. If you want the error + item and to stop everything, I believe if you re-throw the exception from this method, and have no other downstream onErrorContinue, it should terminate the flux. Here is an example from my use of the kafka reactive api

In addition, the item that is passed to onErrorContinue will not be the original item in the flux but will be the object that was attempted to be processed at the step in the reactive chain. For instance, if the chain failed while attempting to convert B -> C but after you converted A -> B, the object you would get in your handler would be B.

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void process() {
    receiver.receiveAutoAck()
            .concatMap(Function.identity())
            .flatMap(this::deserialzeRecord)
            .flatMap(this::processEvent)
            .flatMap(responseSender::send)
            .onErrorContinue(this::handleRecordError)
            .subscribe();
}

private void handleRecordError(Throwable throwable, Object record) {
    log.error("Received error processing record={}", record, throwable);
}
```

If you wanted to terminate the flux and drop the rest of the items just do

```
private void handleRecordError(Throwable throwable, Object record) {
    log.error("Received error processing record={}", record, throwable);
    throw throwable;
}
```